# "show screen updates" tool behavior changes since Android 2.3?

Tags: android, graphics, surfaceview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I keep track of dirty regions in order to use SurfaceView's ability to update only parts of the screen ( lockCanvas(rectangle) ).  The "show screen updates" developer option is really handy for testing this, allowing me to visualize the updated regions.  For example, as I drag an item around the screen, the flashy pink rectangles track it closely.  This is how it works on my phone running Android 2.3.

On my 4.0 tablet, the whole screen flashes pink constantly.

Questions:

- Has the behavior of SurfaceView changed?
- Has the behavior of the "show screen updates" tool changed?
- Does this have something to do with ICS hardware acceleration?

Additional information:

- I observe that the clipping behavior of lockCanvas is still intact. (i.e., my drawing is constrained to the rectangle I pass to lockCanvas(rect) )
- I observe partial screen updates occuring in other ICS apps, so I know the "show screen updates" tool works as desired under some conditions.

Comment: you got any news on this? facing a similar problem ...

Comment: No news.  I did get a tumbleweed badge, though!

Comment: hehe. whats this :=) ? ;D im also searching for the apk from the original dev tools .. (saw a google video some time ago - a few years) but i cant find the either.. :/

Comment: Same, the tool is kind of useless if the whole thing flashes.